# Ошибка:UnboundLocalError: local variable 'winner' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начинаю только изучать python и решил написать простенькую текстовую игру. Написал всё прекрасно работал но теперь захотелось этой игре сделать рестарт чтобы не перезапускать программу а уже в самой игре сделать рестарт.И тут возникает проблема

> ```
> **Игра угадай число
> 4
> Введите число: 4
>  Поздравляю ты победил!
>  Число попыток: 1
> Хотите сыграть ещё Y/N: y
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 37, in <module>
>     game_reset ()
>   File "test.py", line 12, in game_reset
>     if x == winner:
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'winner' referenced before assignment**
> ```

Вот сам код:

```
import time
import random
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init
init()

print(Fore.CYAN + Back.WHITE + Style.DIM)
print("Игра угадай число")
print(Style.RESET_ALL)

winner = random.randint(1,50)
b = 0

def game_reset ():
    if x == winner:
        winner = random.randint(1,50)
        b = 0
    else:
        pass

print(winner)
while True:
    print(Back.BLUE)
    x = input('Введите число: ')
    if x.isdigit():
        x = int(x)
        b += 1
    else:
        print(Back.RED)
        print('Введите челое число.')
        continue
    if x == winner:
        print(Back.GREEN)
        print(" Поздравляю ты победил!\n Число попыток: " + str(b))
        game_next = input('Хотите сыграть ещё Y/N: ')
        if game_next in ('Y','y'):
            game_reset ()
        else:
            print('Спасибо за игру!')
            break
    elif x > winner:
        print(Back.MAGENTA)
        print("Ваше число больше. Попробуйте ещё раз.")
        continue
    else:
        print(Back.MAGENTA)
        print("Ваше число меньше. Попробуйте ещё раз.")
        continue
time.sleep(5)
```

Как решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень хороший совет, но будет работать:

После команды

```
def game_reset ():
```

напишите

```
    global winner
```

Answer (score 1):

Так, вроде, тоже работает. Тогда и функция с перезапуском не нужна.

```
....
if x == winner:
    print(" Поздравляю ты победил!\n Число попыток: " + str(b))
    game_next = input('Хотите сыграть ещё Y/N: ')
    if game_next in ('Y','y'):
        winner = random.randint(1,50)
        b = 0
        continue
....
```

Comment: Да так тоже будет работать но я хотел именно с функции. Так сказать пробую все функции